# Li-ion 3s Battery Charger with Load Sharing

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am requesting help to create a battery charger and load sharing circuit with the following specifications:

- [3s Lithium Ion battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E0KSSZO)
- 12 V at 2 Amps to power [TPA3128D2](http://www.ti.com/product/TPA3128D2) Class-D Amplifier (this is for max volume. Possible to lower the voltage/current to accommodate design constraints)
- 2.7 V at 50 mA, low noise to power STM32F4 microcontroller as well as [external DAC](http://www.ti.com/product/PCM1770) and analog circuitry
- Charging done via USB Micro-B port with USB 2.0 (5 V at 500 mA or 1.5 A)

I am currently considering this design:

- [Power Circuit Module](https://www.batteryspace.com/protection-circuit-module-pcm-with-equilibrium-function-for-3s-li-ion-battery-pack-at-8a-limit.aspx) to handle battery charging and balancing.
- [BQ25713](http://www.ti.com/product/BQ25713) to handle the load sharing/power path management as well as 12 V boost converter
- [TPS62125](http://www.ti.com/product/TPS62125) to output the 2.7 V from the BQ25713 power path
- [BQ24392](http://www.ti.com/product/BQ24392) to handle USB charge detection/enumeration

I would appreciate any help on confirming or denying the viability of this design as well as any suggestions on any improvements that can be made for simplicity.

**Edit**: Simple block diagram as requested.
[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: What design? This is a list of resistors and a bag of ICs. Please outline the general connectivity of your thoughts at block level at least.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Thank you for the suggestion. I've added a block diagram

Comment: I think the BQ25713 is hooked incorrectly. Battery shouldn't be connected to Vsys. Otherwise the rest looks good to me, provided that you will never run your amplifier when charging the battery - uB port won't be able to provide 5A on primary 5V side to run the booster.

Comment: And what about "power Path management" block? How do you envision to match 12V Vsys with 5V Vbus?

Comment: So if you take a look at the first page of the BQ25713 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25713.pdf) the power path management is apart of the design of the IC. It uses power MOSFETs along with outputs from the IC to maintain a 12V Vsys by pulling from the USB port or discharging from the battery. The BQ25713 has an internal Buck/boost converter to help with this.

Comment: BQ25713 is I2C connected to USB?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat No, the I2C bus is used to send charging parameters to the BQ25713 as it is host controlled. My microcontroller will be sending that information over I2C

Comment: Okay, I see that the BQ25713 is a fully-symmetrical converter that can do battery charging from any Vbus, and PD backwards from 12-V battery to any of 5, 9, 15, or 20V Vbus voltages. Cool device indeed... Follow TI WEBBENCH, and you might be Okay.